# In ProviderRepository.php line 95: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, array

Estoy intentando correr el php artisan y me sale

```
In ProviderRepository.php line 95: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array
```

He borrado la carpeta Vendor, he reinstalado el proyecto, actualicé el composer, ejecuté composer install y composer update, ya verifiqué la versión de php en la que debe correr el proyecto y sigue apareciendo el mismo error, llevo días con ese error y ya no se me ocurre nada

Edit
Agrego el código donde marca el error

```
public function loadManifest()
    {
        // The service manifest is a file containing a JSON representation of every
        // service provided by the application and whether its provider is using
        // deferred loading or should be eagerly loaded on each request to us.
        if ($this->files->exists($this->manifestPath)) {
            $manifest = $this->files->getRequire($this->manifestPath);

            if ($manifest) {
                return array_merge(['when' => []], $manifest);
            }
        }
    }
```

la ruta del archivo es vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php

Comment: Agrega el segmento de codigo donde se genera el error

Comment: Hola, prueba de ejecutar un comando cualquiera con -vvv, por ejemplo `php artisan cache:clear -vvv` así verás donde da el error.
Tendrás algún fallo en la configuración, o fichero .env...

Comment: Ya he probado y me sigue botando el mismo error, de hecho no he editado nada de ese archivo pues está en el vendor

Answer (score 0):

Solucione montando todo sobre Homestead y vagrant, lo estaba corriendo sobre el apache localmente pero desconozco aún la razón del porqué no dejaba de marcar el error, al instalar todo en la vbox y correr los comandos ya no marca nada mal